# De-serializing JSON object with property named 'return'

Tags: java, json, gson

Working Java, using Gson.  The input starts:

```
{"success":1,"return":{
```

Unfortunately, as you know, you can not create a field/variable named 'return' in Java.  So, how does one get around this, as the bulk of the data is behind the 'return' field?

This question [Serialize JSON object named "return"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14527804/serialize-json-object-named-return) is related, but the language is C#.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a different name for your field using gson's [Field Naming Support](http://sites.google.com/site/gson/gson-user-guide#TOC-JSON-Field-Naming-Support)

```
public class Whatever {
    private int success;        

    @SerializedName("return")
    private OtherType returnValue;
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Annotate your field with

```
@SerializedName("return")
private SomeType doesntMatter;
```

Gson will use the value given to the `@SerializedName` annotation to map your field by name.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Java annotations of Gson `@SerializedName("return")`.

```
@SerializedName("return")
private String returnField;
```

About Gson annotations you can read [here](http://www.javacreed.com/gson-annotations-example/).